# Why is my SSH connection being closed immediately after pubkey auth succeeds?

Tags: ssh, sshd, cygwin

I've two windows machine and trying to SSH using CYGWIN. It works fine when password prompted. However, when I generated the private/public pair, looks like authentication succeeded, but got the connection closed error.

Here's the detail logs: Please help

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/502537203/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to hostname ([x.x.x.x]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cc -1)

Connection to hostname closed by remote host.
Connection to hostname closed.
Transferred: sent 2056, received 1500 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Comment: I generated this log via ssh -vvv to the remote server and also placed the authorized_keys as well

Comment: You're doing your part just fine, it's the remote server that closes the connection.  Look at the logs of the remote machine.

Comment: In which location of the server, I need to check for logs.

Comment: Check under `\cygwin\var\log\messages`

Comment: I've only below four files under /var/log -> setup.log,
setup.log.full,
sshd.log (no data),
lastlog (huge data). Which one to check?

Answer (score 2):

It's working now. I did the following

1. set the permission for `~/.ssh` 0700
2. all the files under `~/.ssh` 0600
3. run the `sshd` service as `cyg_server id` (created during ssh-host-config)
4. edit `/etc/sshd_config` to allow `PubkeyAuthentication yes`

Comment: There is a `debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).`, so this and the other answers are wrong (for this specific case)

Answer (score 0):

Incompatible ciphers can get negotiated.  Try this:

`ssh -oCiphers=aes128-ctr user@host`

http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/ssh#incompatible-cipher-support

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error when i tried to ssh to **Synology**, as i needed to use Borg Backup. The problem was that i was trying to connect TO a user that wasn't the admin, even though all permissions were correct. When i tried to ssh to the user that was superadmin, connection was not dropped. I don't know if this helps, but this is my experience with this error.