# Can't log into localhost via SSH, but authentication succeeded

Tags: ssh, sshd, cygwin

When I try to use `ssh` to login locally, it closes the connection.

```
$ ssh -vvv Chloe@localhost
...
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to localhost ([::1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cc -1)

Connection to localhost closed by remote host.
Connection to localhost closed.
Transferred: sent 1952, received 1412 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 12675697.7, received 9169101.0
debug1: Exit status -1
```

However, I can login locally

```
Chloe@xps ~
$ login
login: Chloe
Password:
Last login: Thu May 22 00:01:42 from ...
```

And open terminals fine. It is closing the connection from another computer as well. I followed all the steps in this answer ([Why is my SSH connection being closed immediately after pubkey auth succeeds?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323776/why-is-my-ssh-connection-being-closed-immediately-after-pubkey-auth-succeeds)) but it still fails.

```
$ ls -ld ~/.ssh
drwx------+ 1 Chloe None 0 Jul  5  2014 /home/Chloe/.ssh
```

All files are 600, group None.

```
$ ls -l .ssh
total 55
-rw------- 1 Chloe None   395 May 21  2014 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 Chloe None  1638 Apr  6  2009 authorized_keys.old
-rw------- 1 Chloe None   668 Apr  6  2009 id_dsa
-rw------- 1 Chloe None   603 Apr  6  2009 id_dsa.pub
-rw------- 1 Chloe None  1675 Apr  6  2009 id_rsa
...
```

`sshd` running as Cygwin service.

```
$ cygrunsrv -Q sshd
Service             : sshd
Display name        : CYGWIN sshd
Current State       : Running
Controls Accepted   : Stop
Command             : /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Enabled public key authentication and recycled server.

```
$ grep Pubkey  /etc/sshd_config
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

The server log is empty.

```
$ ls -l /var/log/sshd.log
-rw-r--r--+ 1 cyg_server None 0 Nov 21 22:55 /var/log/sshd.log
```

cygwin 2.5.2, Windows 8.1

Comment: "The server log is empty" <-- I'd recommend fixing this before trying to figure out why logging in doesn't work.

Comment: @Patrick How do I fix it?